# Is it possible to route message based on header to particular Queue in Solace Message Router

Tags: solace, solace-mq

Is it possible to route message based on header to particular Queue in Solace Message Router ?

Please give brief details.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code of what you've already tried (as is, your question is rather vague).

Answer (score 2):

Solace Message Router routes messages via topics.

You can publish a message to either:

1. A topic (e.g. `customer/uk/event/logon`)
2. Directly into a queue (e.g. `uk_Queue`)

Queues on the Solace Message Router can be configured to receive one or more topics. For example, the `uk_Queue` can be configured to spool messages that were published to both `customer/uk/event/logon` and `customer/uk/event/logoff`.

You can add an egress selector to consumers that are bound to a queue. With the egress selector, only messages with headers that matches the selector string will be delivered to the consumers. Note that this only applies to delivery of messages to the consumers only. Messages that match the configured topics on the queue will be spooled regardless of whether or not the consumer's selectors match the messages.

Alternatively, you can create a topic endpoint, which allows ingress selectors. Topic endpoints will receive messages that match both the configurable topic and the header fields that matches the configured ingress selector.

You might also be interested in looking at 
http://dev.solacesystems.com/get-started/java-tutorials/topic-queue-mapping_java/
which gives a brief introduction about topic to queue mappings.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that much of this functionality is specific to Solace, and will not be found in other JMS message brokers?  In particular, the ability to configure queues to receive messages published to topics.  I don't think other JMS brokers (e.g. ActiveMQ) have that functionality, do they?